# IntelliJ/GIT: How do I clear/remove files from the commit window?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have just started a new project in IntelliJ and created a new repository on github where I can get commit and push to.

I can see that every time I want to do some implementation I can also see these files under *Changes*. How can I remove these from the *commit* window? I just want to see the changes/implementation I make, not the other file what I will never upload anyway.

How can I remove/clean these?

[image: Here is the files I do not want to see in the commit window]

**update:**
I removed the whole project and tried to add these files to the gitignore file from start and it worked, seemed like a bug or something with my IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have added these files to Git.
You need to add `git rm --cached <filename>` first in order to remove these files from git.

Then you need to right-click on these files in Project view -> `Git` | `Add to .gitignore`

Comment: Hi, I am not using the git commands, I am only using the IntelliJ GUI interface for handeling GIT

Comment: I do understand this. There is no action in UI to remove file from git, therefore you need to run git command in command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .gitignore file.

This is what mine looks like:
[gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81HaR.png)

If you right click on the **app** > **git** you can see an option to add a .gitignore file.

Comment: Hi, I also have gitignore file and looks like this:

### Java template
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log

# BlueJ files
*.ctxt

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*

But I still see things in the commit window :(

Comment: It looks like it's working based on what you're ignoring. I'm not seeing any of those extensions. If you just made changes to your .gitignore, maybe try pushing them?

Comment: I do not know if there was any setting I chose when I started the Github-share project and have not managed to disable it afterwards, but I deleted the whole project and tried again as you said and it works now, thank you!